# Click events firing multiple times on button generated dynamically

Tags: jquery

I generate with jquery, one dynamic div content.
When I click on #change_alert I display an alert.
If I click second time on #change_alert, the alert is displaying 2 times.
If I click third time on  #change_alert, the alert is displaying 3 times.
Do you have an idea to help me and have juste one alert (even if I click more) ?

Thank you

```
var dynamic_content = '<div id="change">'+
           '<div class="view">'+
           '<a href="#" id="change_alert">CLICK</a>'+
            '</div></div>';



$$(document).on('click', '#change_alert', function () {
 alert("TEST !");
});
```

Comment: You're sure it isn't adding the event handler multiple times? Also, maybe if it's bubbling weird you could try passing the `event` to the click handler and adding `event.stopPropagation()` at the top to keep it from triggering on anything else up the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this code and it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dynamic_content = '<div id="change">'+
        '<div class="view">'+
       '<a href="#" id="change_alert">CLICK</a>'+
        '</div></div>';

  $('#content').html(dynamic_content);

  $(document).on('click', '#change_alert', function () {
    alert("TEST !");
  });
});
```

Maybe you are creating more than one dynamic button.